# Milliseconds are lost in Table_Comparison/Map_Operation in timestamps columns

Tags: etl, milliseconds, sap-data-services

I have a data flow in BODS (SAP Data Services) where the milliseconds on a SQL Server column defined as datetime2 are dropped when I am using the Table_Comparison/Map_Operation combination.

When the target table is updated by the Map_Operation, the milliseconds from the Datetime2 column are dropped (i.e. from 11:25:17.388000000 11:25:17.000000000).

As a test, if I use a QueryTransformer to clear and populate the target table, the timestamp column is just fine.

Is there a BODS bug in handling timestamp (datetime2) columns?  Is there something I am missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to place a QueryTransformer in front of the Table_Comparison component.  In the QueryTransformer, specifically change the target column data type from varchar(27) to timestamp.  I also provide a cast in the mapping so to avoid the warnings about converting data to timestamp.

This QueryTransformer addition will also require a sort-by of the columns that make up the primary key IF you are choosing 'Sorted input' as comparison method.  Otherwise you will receive a message that the input table is not sorted.